# connection is lost at the end of the swimline on the plantuml

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

I'm having a little trouble making an activity diagram using plant uml. In this case I want to terminate a process to at one node point (stop). But it looks like I couldn't do this. Please help me. I am a student who just a few days ago used this uml plant.

this is the my plant uml script:

https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/umla/nL9TQzj047o_Nx5zgltGF-10cwGVj0sXWPYyhworjEW-ZliW6FJZUoiP9yXkXIWbVh9kPsPdXhsE2KFAHgjtFc1Z47Aa9mg9TwX_xC5PfVgRsh3bc08c5terKDJcdaoLEuHxiXdkC1pm6UsLwXyBaaml08l6i-xGmXTC20-KSeFnwboIzx2wyTXX2smRjc24MvLFFt8-hI6rP65reBXMK7wR1zRSmdQ4dQHbTB8mu5xR-EQ2kKYP6fAtG9umWGJ5cASfu1P37icRBSbqwqpbD3ooyMWlE3dgFRUi2LPFgBakiJZ2ohenquUFKF8TgRSOEGuhNu8SH7lQfWpVG-EI0x8r-E1s5EDvoR86I4Uwr7P3DQVPjhyAQ4dNGbZKjATGOSWyoNXUioY_USdokhJe5dsESqtFnlykAdy9CQxvNo5sbB3xvmoVHMNkZ7uMfwIBJc2R_dn2mdcj_UlkY1ruz88QlIyeHZgGwqbjYRzMwcIr87clOd9UNPV_sUZV

the end result I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug with the `!pragma useVerticalIf on`, since (I think) turning it off solves the problem (but is not really readable).

Anyway, since all the missing parts lead to `stop`, you can just repeat the stop:

Here's the result:

[image]